# Python list comprehension, with unique items

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a way to make a list comprehension in Python that only contains unique items?

My original idea was to use something like this :
`new_items = [unicode(item) for item in items]`

However, I later realized that I needed to omit duplicate items. So I ended up with this ugly monstrosity :

```
unique_items = []
for item in items :
    unicode_item = unicode(item)
    if unicode_item not in unique_items :
        unique_items.append(unicode_item)
```

Now this is far less pretty (and readable) than a simple list comprehension. So, is there a way to make a list comprehension equivalent to the above code?

Also order does matter, so I can't just use a set comprehension.

Comment: Interesting, my initial thought was that you can do filtering in list comprehensions, but then I realized you'd need access to the new list that you're creating in the filter condition.

Comment: If order matters, how do I know what instance of a repeated item to use? The first, the last, or one in the middle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: @mgilson After a quick check it seems the accepted answer to this question is more efficient than the accepted answer of the linked question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, there is no ordered set, but we can misuse OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
t = "never gonna give you up"
OrderedDict.fromkeys(t).keys()
```

Gives:

```
['n', 'e', 'v', 'r', ' ', 'g', 'o', 'a', 'i', 'y', 'u', 'p']
```

Comment: Oh, very nice. On a side note, try using `repeat(None)` from `itertools` rather than `[None]*len(t)`

Comment: How about `OrderedDict.fromkeys(t).keys()` instead?  [Note that this approach, as well as the set approach, limits us to hashable elements.]

Answer (score 10):

Your original idea works with a set comprehension:

```
new_items = {unicode(item) for item in items}
```

Answer (score 6):

I short one liner might be:

```
s = "some string"
unique_items = [unicode(ch) for ch in sorted(set(s), key=s.index)]
```

Comment: Works, but isn't very efficient for larger lists.

Comment: Nope, but it's short and easy to understand its intent.

Answer (score 4):

Make it a helper function, like so.

```
def unique_iter(iterable):
  seen = set()
  for item in iterable:
    if item in seen:
      continue
    seen.add(item)
    yield item

for ch in unique_iter("never gonna give you up"):
  print ch,
```

outputs

> n e v r   g o a i y u p