# Python list comprehension: adding unique elements into list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write simpler code for adding unique elements into a python list. I have a dataset that contains a list of dictionaries, and I'm trying to iterate through a list inside the dictionary

Why doesn't this work? It's adding all the items, including the duplicates, instead of adding unique items.

```
unique_items = []
unique_items = [item for d in data for item in d['items'] if item not in unique_items]
```

vs. the longer form which works:

```
unique_items = []
for d in data:
    for item in d['items']:
        if (item not in unique_items):
            unique_items.append(item)
```

Is there a way of making this work using list comprehension, or am I stuck with using double for loops? I want to keep the ordering for this.

Here's the list of dictionaries:

```
[{"items":["apple", "banana"]}, {"items":["banana", "strawberry"]}, {"items":["blueberry", "kiwi", "apple"]}]
```

output should be ["apple", "banana", "strawberry", "blueberry", "kiwi"]

I noticed someone asking a similar question on another post: [Python list comprehension, with unique items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681753/python-list-comprehension-with-unique-items), but I was wondering if there's another way to do it without OrderedDict or if that's the best way

Comment: Please provide more information: your list of dicts would be of great use to anyone providing help.

Comment: use a set better, it get rip of all duplicates for you

Comment: Do you want to keep the ordering?

Comment: Yes, ordering is important

Comment: In that case the response in the other question is the easiest way. If you really want alternatives check [OrderedSet recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

l = [{"items":["apple", "banana"]}, {"items":["banana", "strawberry"]}, {"items":["blueberry", "kiwi", "apple"]}]
OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(d['items'] for d in l)).keys() # ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'kiwi']
```

If you want alternatives check `OrderedSet` [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) and [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set) based on it.

Answer (score 3):

`all_items` isn't continuously overwritten during the list comprehension, so you're constantly looking for things in an empty list.

I would do this instead:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4,]

items = []
_ = [items.append(d) for d in data if d not in items]
print(items)
```

and I get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But there are more efficient ways to do this anyway.

Comment: What are some more efficient ways of doing this?

Comment: `set` like in the other answer, `numpy.unique`, etc

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `set`?

e.g. -

```
>>> data = {1: {'items': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, 2: {'items': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}}
>>> {val for item in data for val in data[item]['items']}
>>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

If you want a list:

```
>>> list(repeat above)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Instead of the curly braces `{}` for the set you could also just use the `set` keyword, since the braces may be overly obscure for some.

Here's a link to the [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#set-displays)

Comment: It might be worth to note that this doesn't preserve the ordering like the example code in question or the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681753/python-list-comprehension-with-unique-items