# Beautiful soup, list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I looked at site html source, and found what i need for `namePlayer`, it was 4 column and 'a' tag. And i tried to find it at `answers.append` with `'namePlayer': cols[3].a.text`

But when i complile it, i get IndexError. Then i try to change index to 2,3,4,5 but nothing.

Issue: why i get IndexError: list index out of range, when all is ok(i think :D)

source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"


def get_html(url):
    opener = AppURLopener()
    response = opener.open(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find(id='answers')

    answers = []

    for row in table.find_all('div')[16:]:
        cols = row.find_all('div')

    answers.append({
        'namePlayer': cols[3].a.text
    })


    for answer in answers:
        print(answers)


def main():
    parse(get_html('http://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page=1'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Double check what `cols` is. Apparently it doesn't have 4 elements.

Comment: it has 4 elements

Comment: It can't, or it wouldn't cause that error. Make sure the data that you're trying to get isn't inside of another structure like an outer list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `cols` during your loop. The last length of `cols` is zero hence your error.

```
for row in table.find_all('div')[16:]:
    cols = row.find_all('div')
    print(len(cols))
```

Run the above and you will see `cols` ends up at length 0.

This might also occur elsewhere in loop so you should test the length and also decide if your logic needs updating. Also, you need to account for whether there is a child `a` tag.

So, you might, for example, do the following (bs4 4.7.1+ required):

```
answers = []

for row in table.find_all('div')[16:]:
    cols = row.find_all('div:has(>a)')
    if len(cols) >= 3:
         answers.append({
        'namePlayer': cols[3].a.text
    })
```

Note that `answers` has been properly indented so you are working with each `cols` value. This may not fit your exact use case as I am unsure what your desired result is. If you state the desired output I will update accordingly.

---

EDIT:

playerNames

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
answer_blocks = soup.select('[id^=answer_]')
names = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('[id^=answer_] .left-side a')]
unique_names = {i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('[id^=answer_] .left-side a')}
```

---

You can preserve order and de-duplicated with OrderedDict (this by [@Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12681879/6241235) - other solutions in that Q&A)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from collections import OrderedDict

r = requests.get('https://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
answer_blocks = soup.select('[id^=answer_]')
names = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('[id^=answer_] .left-side a')]
unique_names = OrderedDict.fromkeys(names).keys()
```

Comment: Code did not output answers ;(. I want to get PlayerName for each answer in website.

Comment: please can you provide examples of these playerNames that should come out.

Comment: 'namePlayer': VANTY3
'namePlayer': KK#キング
'namePlayer': memories. and etc all the nicknames of the people who did answer this topic

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, i get what i want. But I didn’t understand how he sorts these names, is it randomly?

Comment: The list will be in the correct order. The set has no order (the unique). You could instead de-duplicate in a loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Time to understand your code >< :D for find other list elements

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you are providing an index for which a list element does not exist. Remember index starts at 0. example: 0,1,2,3. So if I ask for element 10 I would get an Index error.

Answer (score 0):

why you use for loop for finding all div tag :

```
for row in table.find_all('div')[16:]:
        cols = row.find_all('div')
```

by using this you got all the tag you want

```
cols = table.find_all('div')[16:]
```

so just change your code with this code and you got your answer.